# Firebase Console Error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We were not receiving any of these errors until yesterday. Now it seems that some of our users are receiving the following console errors when they attempt to log in to our website:

```
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=67786327&cb=1&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=65618729&cb=2&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=32392592&cb=3&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=32634599&cb=4&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=4599472&cb=5&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=83620720&cb=6&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=50746401&cb=7&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=52157056&cb=8&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=53706052&cb=9&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=82867820&cb=10&v=5 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
login:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://app.oursite.io/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://app.oursite.io/#!/login'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
our-app-3.0.7-1466535315061.js:27 GET https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=1457264&cb=11&v=5 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(anonymous function) @ our-app-3.0.7-1466535315061.js:27
our-app-3.0.7-1466535315061.js:27 GET https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=58021504&cb=12&v=5 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(anonymous function) @ our-app-3.0.7-1466535315061.js:27
our-app-3.0.7-1466535315061.js:27 GET https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=7127936&cb=13&v=5 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(anonymous function) @ our-app-3.0.7-1466535315061.js:27
our-app-3.0.7-1466535315061.js:27 GET https://our-app.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=67025645&cb=14&v=5 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(anonymous function) @ our-app-3.0.7-1466535315061.js:27
```

It seems like we may not be the only site experiencing such issues starting in the last 24 hours:
https://app.roll20.net/forum/post/3558225/campaigns-not-loading

One specific user is able to log in on their mobile data network, but not on their wifi. Other users have been able to log in using an incognito window.

Is this something we can resolve on our end? Is this an intermittent firebase issue? Does it have to do with our mixed content? I guess I'm not sure why it happened to our two unrelated websites at around the same time.